# Elasticsearch searching for exact tags

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

Let's say I have the following documents

```
doc1: "blue water"
doc2: "extra blue water"
doc3: "blue waters"
```

I'm looking for a way to handle the following scenarios

If a user searches for "blue water" I want him to receive doc1 and doc3 (meaning that it will ignore doc2 and will also have an analyzers that will be able to stem tokens like in doc3).

If I'm using query_string, for example, I'm receiving doc2 as well as doc1 and doc3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stemmer](http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html) along with the [percolate query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html)

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "tags": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "query": {
        "type": "percolator"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "tags": {
        "query": "blue waters",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "tags": {
        "query": "extra blue water",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "tags": {
        "query": "blue water",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "tags": "blue water"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67671916",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.26152915,
        "_source": {
          "query": {
            "match_phrase": {
              "tags": {
                "query": "blue waters",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": {
          "_percolator_document_slot": [
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67671916",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.26152915,
        "_source": {
          "query": {
            "match_phrase": {
              "tags": {
                "query": "blue water",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": {
          "_percolator_document_slot": [
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Lior Magen did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use prefix search in this case. If you look for `blue water`, then as per prefix search it will give doc1 and doc3.

For prefix search :

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix":{
            "doc": word
        }
     }
}
```

Here word = blue water

You can have a look at [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html).